# how to make vertical image thumbnail slider responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bxslider

I am using `bxSlider` in my project. I want to make vertical and horizontal thumbnail slider with multiple images. I am using bootstrap framework in my project to achieve responsiveness. I using bxslider to make   thmbnail slider for both horizontal and vertical. http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified#example

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stvkd09c/3/)

Code:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#bxslider-vertical .bxslider').bxSlider({
                mode: 'vertical', 
                infiniteLoop: false,
                pager:false,
                slideWidth: 200,
                maxSlides: 3,
                minSlides: 3,                
                slideMargin: 10                                 
            });

             $('#bxslider-horizontal .bxslider').bxSlider({
                mode: 'horizontal', 
                infiniteLoop: false,
                pager:false,
                slideWidth: 200,
                maxSlides: 4,
                minSlides: 2,                
                slideMargin: 10 
            });
});
```

But as you see vertical slider is not at all responsive if i resize browser window ?
And how to align image at center ? As I have both portraits and landscape image.

Comment: What is the vertical slider supposed to be doing when you resize the browser? I'm thinking that since you set the `mode` in `.bxSlider()`, you'll have to use Javascript (`$(window).resize()`) to change the slider instance.

Comment: when i resize window to 320px (i-phone view) like horizontal slider shows 2 images vertical slider does not show 2 images it shows 3 images all the time...

Answer (score 0):

bxslider is a responsive content slider.
However, for vertical slider you need to mention the number of slides that will be visible, and maxSlides attribute is not considered for vertical sliders.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1pprLL9/)

```
     $('#bxslider-vertical .bxslider').bxSlider({
                mode: 'vertical', 
                infiniteLoop: false,
                pager:false,
                slideWidth: 200,
                minSlides: 2,                
                slideMargin: 10                                 
            });
```

From their official documentation:

*Vertical carousels follow most of the same rules as horizontal carousels. However, the maxSlides setting is not used as vertical carousels will always have only one slide across. Therefore, we do not have to accomodate different screen widths with this setting.*